# How do we use 죠 at the end of question ?

Tags: grammar

I know it's short of 지요 but how do you use it in questions and what else do you use at the end of the questions if not this ?

Comment: use it same as you would 지요, like 예요/이에요

Answer (score 1):

You would use 지요/죠 at the end of a question where you want to "check" with someone. As in, not a regular question, but you know the answer and you want to check if someone agrees with you.

For example:

Delicious?

> 맛있어요?

vs

Delicious isn't it?  (You aren't *really* asking, since you already think it's tasty, you are kind of just expecting them to agree with you).

> 맛있죠?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below.

> 우리는 한국어 공부를 하지요.
>   우리는 한국어 공부를 하죠.

or

In questions

> 하겠지요?
>   => 하겠죠?